# Transaction exited with an error (status 0) after invoking swapExactETHForTokens several times

Tags: solidity, truffle, uniswap

I am experimenting with UniswapV2 on a forked local environment (`ganache --fork [mainnet]`. I am able to deploy my own token, interact with the uniswapv2 contracts located on the  fork and add liquidity to token/eth pair. Next I am able to do one `swapExactETHForTokens` from an arbitrary test account, but when trying to swap again it gives me:

```
StatusError: Transaction: 0xb0ccae2a2e90cb03d983764f10ec30128accbd252571b3b0062f77b990dd2c2b exited with an error (status 0).
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\test.js:89:21)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

What I've already looked at:

1. Set appropriate approvals (none since sending eth)
2. Accounts have sufficient balance (yes test account 1000 eth)
3. Errors in contract: Token contract is ERC20 default token.

Really looking for some clues on where this error originates from, the code is to much to share here so I've created a repo for it which can be found at: https://github.com/4compu/TestToken.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bump into it myself, didn't find a solution. Found a workaround: swapped eth to weth manually in my contract and used `swapExactTokensForTokens` instead of `swapExactETHForTokens`, worked as a charm